# Import Error while running pytest in virtualenv

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, virtualenv, pytest

I am trying to run my pytest (bdd) test cases in virtualenv. I have created a requirements.txt (using pip freeze) file in the root folder as below.

```
apipkg==1.5
atomicwrites==1.3.0
attrs==19.1.0
behave==1.2.6
certifi==2019.6.16
chardet==3.0.4
chromedriver==2.24.1
contextlib2==0.6.0.post1
coverage==4.5.4
docker==4.2.0
execnet==1.7.1
extras==1.0.0
Faker==4.1.1
fixtures==3.0.0
fuzzywuzzy==0.17.0
glob2==0.7
html-testRunner==1.2
html2text==2020.1.16
HTMLParser==0.0.2
idna==2.8
imaplib2==2.45.0
importlib-metadata==0.23
Jinja2==2.9.5
lettuce==0.2.23
lettuce-webdriver==0.3.5
linecache2==1.0.0
Mako==1.1.0
MarkupSafe==1.1.1
mock==3.0.5
more-itertools==7.0.0
packaging==19.2
parse==1.11.1
parse-type==0.4.2
path==15.0.0
path.py==12.5.0
pbr==5.4.2
pi==0.1.2
pipenv==2018.11.26
pluggy==0.13.0
py==1.8.0
pyparsing==2.4.2
pyperclip==1.7.0
PyQt5==5.13.0
PyQt5-sip==4.19.18
PyQtWebEngine==5.13.0
pytest==5.1.2
pytest-bdd==3.2.1
pytest-docker-fixtures==1.3.6
pytest-fixture-config==1.7.0
pytest-forked==1.1.3
pytest-html==2.0.0
pytest-metadata==1.8.0
pytest-ordering==0.6
pytest-shutil==1.7.0
pytest-splinter==2.0.1
pytest-virtualenv==1.7.0
pytest-xdist==1.31.0
pytest-yield==1.0.0
python-dateutil==2.8.1
python-mimeparse==1.6.0
python-subunit==1.3.0
PyYAML==5.3.1
QScintilla==2.11.2
requests==2.22.0
responses==0.10.9
selenium==3.141.0
six==1.12.0
splinter==0.11.0
sure==1.4.11
termcolor==1.1.0
testtools==2.3.0
text-unidecode==1.3
traceback2==1.4.0
unittest2==1.1.0
urllib3==1.24.1
virtualenv==16.7.2
virtualenv-clone==0.5.3
wcwidth==0.1.7
websocket-client==0.57.0
zipp==0.6.0
```

I have created the virtual env, activated the same and installed the dependencies using the below commands.

```
virtualenv test
source test/bin/activate
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

However when I am trying to run the test cases, am getting the below errors.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/test/bin/pytest", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/test/lib/python3.7/site-packages/_pytest/config/__init__.py", line 59, in main
    config = _prepareconfig(args, plugins)
  File "/test/lib/python3.7/site-packages/_pytest/config/__init__.py", line 209, in _prepareconfig
    pluginmanager=pluginmanager, args=args
  File "/test/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pluggy/hooks.py", line 286, in __call__
    return self._hookexec(self, self.get_hookimpls(), kwargs)
  File "/test/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pluggy/manager.py", line 92, in _hookexec
    return self._inner_hookexec(hook, methods, kwargs)
  File "/test/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pluggy/manager.py", line 86, in <lambda>
    firstresult=hook.spec.opts.get("firstresult") if hook.spec else False,
  File "/test/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pluggy/callers.py", line 203, in _multicall
    gen.send(outcome)
  File "/test/lib/python3.7/site-packages/_pytest/helpconfig.py", line 89, in pytest_cmdline_parse
    config = outcome.get_result()
  File "/test/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pluggy/callers.py", line 80, in get_result
    raise ex[1].with_traceback(ex[2])
  File "/test/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pluggy/callers.py", line 187, in _multicall
    res = hook_impl.function(*args)
  File "/test/lib/python3.7/site-packages/_pytest/config/__init__.py", line 720, in pytest_cmdline_parse
    self.parse(args)
  File "/test/lib/python3.7/site-packages/_pytest/config/__init__.py", line 928, in parse
    self._preparse(args, addopts=addopts)
  File "/test/lib/python3.7/site-packages/_pytest/config/__init__.py", line 874, in _preparse
    self.pluginmanager.load_setuptools_entrypoints("pytest11")
  File "/test/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pluggy/manager.py", line 297, in load_setuptools_entrypoints
    plugin = ep.load()
  File "/test/lib/python3.7/site-packages/importlib_metadata/__init__.py", line 92, in load
    module = import_module(match.group('module'))
  File "/test/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "/test/lib/python3.7/site-packages/_pytest/assertion/rewrite.py", line 140, in exec_module
    exec(co, module.__dict__)
  File "/test/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pytest_yield/plugin.py", line 11, in <module>
    from _pytest.python import Generator
ImportError: cannot import name 'Generator' from '_pytest.python' (/test/lib/python3.7/site-packages/_pytest/python.py)
```

Can you help me understand what I am missing here? I tried with different versions of pytest, without luck. However the test cases are running fine in my local without any issues.

Comment: Try downloading pytest11 package

Comment: @NavanK., it would be of great help if you could explain how this can be done and how this helps

Comment: The pytest package that you have in your virtualenv might not be compatible . A finer version , pytest11 , can be downloaded in the same manner like other packages and it might help you.

Comment: @NavanK. thanks for the reply. I have tried with the latest stable version (5.4.3) of pytest without much luck. Could you suggest something else?

Comment: Try using anaconda. Create a virtual environment in there.

Comment: Seems like it's the `pytest-yield` plugin that's causing the trouble, try uninstalling that one.

Comment: @hoefling , this seems to do the trick, I guess there were compatibility issues between pytest-yield plugin and the latest versions of pytest which triggered the error. thanks for the solution. May be you can post the solution in the answer section so that it will be helpful for others as well. Meanwhile I will try the solution across different virtualenv's to test this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an open issue with `pytest-yield` that prevents it to work with latest `pytest` version (5.1 and up): [#6](https://github.com/devova/pytest-yield/issues/6). This means that you have either to downgrade to an older version of `pytest`:

```
$ pip install "pytest<5"
```

Or uninstall `pytest-yield` until the above issue is resolved:

```
$ pip uninstall -y pytest-yield
```